# How can you link version numbers between build configurations of a TeamCity project?

Tags: rake, teamcity

I'd like to have 3 distinct builds within a TeamCity project (Development, QA, Production).  With the dependencies linked (Production can't build without a successful QA, and QA can't build without a successful Development), I'd like to propagate the version numbers through the builds.

Development Build => v 1.0.1.0
QA Build => on successful build set version to v1.0.1.0

Is there a way to set a build configuration version to a different builds version?

I'm using TeamCity 4.0.2, runner is Rake, building VS2008 solutions.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you have snapshot dependencies for Dev->QA->Production build, you can reference build number from Dev build in QA and Production builds.

Please read http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/message/5231290 for details how to do it.

**Update:**
The recent information on how to achieve this is available in [this TeamCity How-To question](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/How+To...#HowTo...-SharetheBuildnumberforBuildsinaChainBuild).