# TeamCity - referencing a build number from a different Build configuration

Tags: deployment, msbuild, teamcity

I am in the process of setting up teamcity and msbuild to automate our build process a good deal more than we do now. Each project that we work on is being set up as a seperate project in teamcity, and each of those projects is being set up with 3 build configurations: Development, staging, and live. Development is our standard CI build that runs after each checkin. Staging and live perform build and deployment to the appropriate environment.

Our live builds will be numbered using the teamcity counter. But I would like to set up the staging build to number its builds as betas of the next Live build. So if the live build is at version 6 then I would like to number my staging builds as v7b1, v7b2 etc. Is there any way of doing this either in teamcity or as part of an msbuild script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you link version numbers between build configurations of a TeamCity project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580138/how-can-you-link-version-numbers-between-build-configurations-of-a-teamcity-proj)

Answer (score 8):

[How can you link version numbers between build configurations of a TeamCity project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580138/how-can-you-link-version-numbers-between-build-configurations-of-a-teamcity-proje/581644#581644)

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just put "v7b{0}" in the "Build number format" box?

Comment: This is of course one way to to do it but is a manual process. This was something that I was hoping to automate.